# props saying unidentified when using .concat on array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So the items array in my props contains items when logging but when trying to add to the array when using `.concat` it says `Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined`

```
export default (props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  const samples = samplesAsOrderItems();
  const allBasketItems = items.concat(samples);

  return (
    <div className="OrderDetails">
      <h4 className="OrderDetails__title">Order summary</h4>

      <div className="OrderDetails__content">
        <div className="OrderDetails__items">
          {items && items.map( (orderItem, index) => {
            return (
              <OrderItem
                key={index}
                {...orderItem}
                displayType={DisplayType.MINIMAL}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>

        <TotalBreakdown
          {...getTotalBreakdownFromOrder(props)}
        />

      </div>
    </div>
  );

  function samplesAsOrderItems() {
    const sampleItems = get(props, 'samples[0]', undefined);
    var orderItems: Mothership.IOrderItem[] = [];

    if (sampleItems === undefined) {
      return orderItems;
    } else {
      sampleItems.product.bundleItems.map( (bundleItem, index) => (
        bundleItem.siblings.map( (sibling) => (
          orderItems.push(bundleToOrderItem(sibling, sampleItems.subTotal.currencyCode))
        ))
      ));
      return orderItems;
    }
  }
};
```

I'm fairly new to typescript and react and am really struggling as to why this is happening.

Comment: What type is `props`? At the moment it's `any`, so you get exactly that: no static type checking, any garbage can be passed there

Comment: @zerkms ive only just joined this codebase but the props being passed is large and items is a small part of it so it is `any` at this time

Comment: So start gradually typing it then. Ensure `items` is a `string[]` first.

Answer (score 1):

Where you're using the Component you're not passing through an Array in items. That's the only way items.concat would fail with that error as props are immutable.

When using this Component make sure you call it like `<ItemDetails items={[]}/>`

The type of things plays no role in how code executes at runtime in Typescript, so "any" plays no part in changing how the code executes.

Comment: "so "any" plays no part in changing how the code executes." --- wat. If `props` was typed - the would not call a `.concat` method on `undefined`, it just would not pass a type check. It really makes a little sense to opt-in TS then deliberately use `any`. "When using this Component make sure"--- that's the whole idea behind using ts, you don't need to "make sure" anymore, a compiler ensures for you.

Comment: all types including "any" play no part in how the code executes, it doesn't matter if props is typed. The compiler ensures you IF you're code is properlly typed and you have strictNullChecks on in your Tsconfig

Comment: You're not following: **IF** the code was typed properly - the problem would never have happened. Regardless the fact the TS does not exist in runtime, using it properly would not let the problem occur in the very first place.

Comment: See the difference: you're suggesting "make sure" which is a human factor problem, and I'm suggesting to type it - so that it was checked **automatically**.

Comment: Oh i see what you're saying now i thought you were "O.P" so i was reading that in the perspective of "O.P". Yes it's true that if you properly type "props" the compiler will ensure you.